# using struct with mapping in solidity

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

i am developing a locker smartcontract where user can lock their erc20 token. i have successfully develop the adding(lock) functionality but having difficulty developing the withdraw function. for with draw function i want to implement-

- user can only able to withdraw after the locking period &
  *the wallet add the token can only be able to withdraw.

here is the code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract lock  {
    address public owner;
    
   struct Lock{
       address token;
       uint amount;
       uint endtime;

    }

    constructor() {
     owner= msg.sender;
     
    }

    mapping(address => Lock) public tokenLock;

    function locker( address _token, uint256 _amount, uint _time) public{
        
        tokenLock[msg.sender]= Lock(_token, _amount, _time);
        IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),_amount);
       }
    
   function chkBalance(address _token) public view returns (uint){
     return  IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
   }

   

   >  function claim(address _token) public { 
>          require(block.timestamp >time);
> 
>        }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain more explicitly what is not working please ?

Comment: look at the claim function. i want to implement claim function as such-                         user can only able to withdraw after the locking period & *the wallet add the token can only be able to withdraw.

Comment: Gotcha. You could load the struct in the memory using:
`Lock memory myLock = tokenLock[msg.sender];`
And access those variables from here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your issue and implementing my logic in your `claim` function.
I put also some notes for understand you your errors.
You can see this smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract lock  {
    address public owner;
    
    struct Lock {
        address token;
        uint amount;
        uint endtime;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    mapping(address => Lock) public tokenLock;

    function locker( address _token, uint256 _amount, uint _time) public{
        // NOTE: Add 'block.timestamp' plus time for manage lock time  
        tokenLock[msg.sender] = Lock(_token, _amount, block.timestamp + _time);
        IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),_amount);
    }
    
    function chkBalance(address _token) public view returns (uint){
        return IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function claim(address _token) public { 
        // NOTE: Retrieve the end time from Lock struct
        uint time = tokenLock[msg.sender].endtime;
        require(block.timestamp > time, "You must to attend your locktime!");
        address _to = msg.sender;
        uint amountTokenInSmartContract = IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
        // NOTE: Use 'transfer' method for send '_to' address the amount of token locked inside smart contract  
        IERC20(_token).transfer(_to, amountTokenInSmartContract);
    }

}
```

Comment: kerry99 your way of explaining is awesome.